# Using AFIncrementalStore with a WebSockets Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, websocket, afnetworking, afincrementalstore

I'm attempting to adopt AFIncrementalStore for a Mac app that talks to App.Net. Unlike the example applications that come with the framework, I'm using the streaming APIs, with a websocket connection. For this I was using SocketRocket. These parts are working fine: I'm able to set up a request connection to ADN and get a connection ID back. It's this connection ID I supply to the later requests to ADN APIs.

My problem is that the Core Data stack is initialized and firing before I get my first connection ID back from ADN. I'm not sure how to handle this situation.

Currently, I have this code in my app delegate:

```
self.socketConnection = [[MUNConnectionManager alloc] init];
self.socketConnection.delegate = self;
```

My connection manager implements a delegate that calls back to the app delegate when the connection ID has been received:

```
# pragma mark MUNConnectionManager delegate method
- (void)didReceiveConnectionId:(NSString*)connectionId
{
    self.connectionId = connectionId;
}
```

So once this connection ID is received, that's when I'd like to boot AFIncrementalStore into action. But this is perhaps a full second or so after launch, and my AFIncrementalStore client is already crapping out because it doesn't have that connection ID.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer to this. In my XIB I have an array controller with the "prepares content" checkbox on. That would have triggered the data store and loaded up all the Core Data stack. When I uncheck that box it doesn't load, and my ADN delegate is free to pull the ID.

So if anyone else runs into this, the answer is the CD stack doesn't load until you try to hit it.